# Opera Mobile not showing jQuery Mobile icons

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, opera-mobile

I have a problem in Opera Mobile browser which is failing to display jQuery dialog icons. This is how this looks like:

[image]

As you can see, icon left from error, which should be close button (x) is missing, as well as the icon in the "OK" button. Also, "Automatic" button in the background (lower right part of the screenshot) also lacks its icon.

Any idea what might be the problem, having in mind that this is only happening with Opera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. When I was downloading jQuery Mobile files, I thought I only needed js and css files, but it turned out that there is a folder named "Images" which contains all jQuery Mobile icons :)

To conclude, don't download only js and css files, download and deploy the whole zip file!

Answer (score 1):

I also have issues with Opera Mobile not rendering Jquery Mobile elements -

try this to test...

```
 <a href="tel:02258588528" style="color:White;" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-theme="a">Call Now - 02258 588 528</a>
```

this should show the gear - if that doesnt work then i would say you have issues with CSS and the image mapping. To resolve that you should get fresh CSS from the Jquery Mobile download pack

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I'm experiencing the same problem with your test anchor; I tried adding new fresh version of jquery mobile css file, but that didn't work out either.